# Angular / Redux / Reducers not importing

Tags: angularjs, redux

I seem to have a possible injection issue with my Combined Reducers in angular. Angular is to create the Redux store then pass this instance to React. I'm using *ngReact* and *ngRedux* libs for this purpose.

Please excuse any typos. The application compiles correctly via Webpack and runs, but with this problem detailed here.

Below is my simple Reducer

```
const botsReducerTemp = (state = [] , action) => {  
    switch(action.type) {
      case 'ADD_BOT_API':

        return state

      default:
        return state;
  }
}
export default botsReducerTemp;
```

I have an *index.js* in a folder named *reducers* that combines this reducer (and several others but not shown in this question)

```
   import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
    import botsReducerTemp from './bots/bot-reducersTemp';

    const rootReducer =  combineReducers ({
        botsReducerTemp
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

In my angular 1.5 app I have a *module.js* (the paths to the imports are correct and compile via WebPack)

Note: The import of `import rootReducer from '../../reducers'`  this is the import of the combined reducer of *index.js*

```
import ngreact from 'ngreact';
import ngRedux from 'ng-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from '../../reducers'

angular
  .module('meso-app', [
    'meso-core',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'chart.js',
    'ngRedux'
  ])

 .config(($ngReduxProvider) => {
      $ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith(rootReducer, [thunk], [logger], [{ tests: {id: 1, isDone: false, text: 'bot 1'}}] );
      console.log('rootReducer = ' + typeof(rootReducer));
      console.dir(rootReducer);
  })

......lot's other angular boot stuff....
```

**The problem** is in my *.config* *rootReducer* appears as *not available* when viewed in Chrome debug.

*$ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith* executes ok, but because rootReducer is empty the Redux store is not built.

*rootReducer* is a function that is executed/parsed in *.createStoreWith*

So how do I inject / import this function  ?

Answer (score 0):

In *module.js*  I removed the import and replaced it with a require

```
var rootReducer = require('../../reducers');
```

Then in my .config i used

```
 let rootReducers = rootReducer.rootReducer;
```

and then called createStoreWith as below

```
  $ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith(rootReducers, [thunk], null, [{ tests: {id: 1, isDone: false, text: 'bot 1'}}] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm following a similar pattern, and I was able to get it working via the following:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { ExampleReducer } from './example';

export const RootReducer = combineReducers({
    example: ExampleReducer
});
```

and then in your .config:

```
...
import { RootReducer } from '../../reducers';
...
.config(($ngReduxProvider) => {
  $ngReduxProvider.createStoreWith(RootReducer, [thunk], [logger], [{ tests: {id: 1, isDone: false, text: 'bot 1'}}] );
  console.log('rootReducer = ' + typeof(RootReducer));
  console.dir(RootReducer);
})
```